# Can I use *have had* for this statement about the past?

Tags: grammar, american-english

Here is the scenario: some issue happened in the system and I need to find out and report to the manager what happened to one job which didn't run last night. Can I put it this way?

> I will take a look into it to find out what **have had** happen to the job.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Have had" versus "had"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6663/have-had-versus-had)

Answer (score 1):

No. You can say: "happened" or "had happened" depending on whether you mean   a recent past event (happened), or an event further in the past (had happened).

Alex has his arm in a cast. What happened to Alex?

"Had happened" is used for precision in a comparative timeframe. Most people just say "happened."

Hope this helps.

Comment: what about "have happened" is it means more recently happened?