# have car vs have had car?

Tags: difference, present-tense

What is the difference between the following sentences?

1. I have a car.
2. I have had a car.
3. I have a car from 2 January 2020.
4. I have had a car since 2 January 2020.

Is there any difference between the 3 and 4 or they are interchangeable?

Comment: #3 isn't idiomatic. And in case you didn't realise, #2 strongly implies *I did have a car in the past, **but I no longer have a car now***. But this is off-topic proofreading

Comment: Related: [“Have had” versus “had”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/6663/9161)

Answer (score 1):

I would assume #3 would have to mean "I have a car that was made on 2 January 2020".

Answer (score 0):

**1. I have a car.**

Currently I own a car.

**2. I have had a car.**

In the past, at times I owned one or more cars, but right now I probably don't own one.

**3. I have a car from 2 January 2020.**

Not correct.

**4. I have had a car since 2 January 2020.**

Currently I own a car, and I acquired it 2 January 2020.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the previous answer, "I have a car from 2 January 2020" is not entirely impossible to say, although you probably wouldn't be precise to a day with a car - you'd be more likely to say "I have a car from 2020". And it would mean: *I own a car that was made in 2020.*